# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4) Python

Tags: python

I created a function that find the best parameters for Random Forest Classifier, but I riceved this error "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)".
I don't want to use RandomSearchCV or GridSearchCV. Could anyone help me?
The code is the following:

```
depth_options= range(8,30)
sample_split_options= range(2, 200)
sample_leaf_options= range(1, 100)
estimator_options= range(10, 1000)

# for loop to iterate for each leaf size
for leaf_size,split_size,n_est,depth in sample_leaf_options, sample_split_options, depth_options, estimator_options  :
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = n_est, n_jobs = -1,random_state = 42, 
min_samples_leaf = leaf_size, min_samples_split=split_size, max_depth=depth)
model.fit(X4_train,y_train)
print(leaf_size, split_size, n_est, depth)
print ("AUC - ROC : ", roc_auc_score(y_test,model.predict_proba(X4_test)[:,1]))
```

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: @Guy the error is in this line "for leaf_size,split_size,n_est,depth in sample_leaf_options, sample_split_options, depth_options, estimator_options  : "

Comment: indentation error after for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need separate for loops:

```
for leaf_size in sample_leaf_options:
    for split_size in sample_split_options:
        for n_est in depth_options:
            for depth in estimator_options:
                model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = n_est, n_jobs = -1,random_state = 42, min_samples_leaf = leaf_size, min_samples_split=split_size, max_depth=depth)
                model.fit(X4_train,y_train)
                print(leaf_size, split_size, n_est, depth)
                print ("AUC - ROC : ", roc_auc_score(y_test,model.predict_proba(X4_test)[:,1]))
```

Edit: To save the highest score:

```
highest_score = 0
highest_leaf_size = 0
highest_split_size = 0
highest_n_est = 0
highest_depth = 0

# for loop to iterate for each leaf size
for leaf_size in sample_leaf_options:
    for split_size in sample_split_options:
        for n_est in depth_options:
            for depth in estimator_options:
                model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = n_est, n_jobs = -1,random_state = 42, min_samples_leaf = leaf_size, min_samples_split=split_size, max_depth=depth)
                model.fit(X4_train,y_train)
                score = roc_auc_score(y_test,model.predict_proba(X4_test)[:,1])
                if score > highest_score:
                    highest_score = score
                    highest_leaf_size = leaf_size
                    highest_split_size = split_size
                    highest_n_est = n_est
                    highest_depth = depth
print(highest_leaf_size, highest_split_size, highest_n_est, highest_depth)
print ("AUC - ROC : ", highest_score)
```

Comment: How can I print only the best combinations of paremeters?

Comment: How do you decide what is the best option? Is it the one with the highest `roc_auc_score`?

Comment: Yes, I would the highest roc_auc_score

Comment: You would generally save the highest score outside the loop and display it once the loop is done. If you want to display the highest leaf_size, split_size and the other variables, you can save those as well when the highest score is reached

Comment: I understand, but how can I change my code?